# can't pickle lock objects

Tags: python, pyspark, pickle

i get this error when using this code :

```
def createLabeledPoints(fields):
    q1 = fields[1]
    q2 = fields[12]
    q3 = fields[23]
result = fields[40]
return LabeledPoint(result, array([q1, q2, q3])

spark = SparkSession \
.builder \
.appName("myApp") \
.config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/newumc.classification_data") \
.config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/newumc.classification_data") \
.getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").load()


dt = df.rdd.map(createLabeledPoints)
model111 = DecisionTree.trainClassifier(dt, numClasses=467, 
categoricalFeaturesInfo={0:2,1:2, 2:2}, impurity='gini', maxDepth=30, maxBins=32)
```

but when i want to save my model "model111" and using it with flask

```
import cPickle as pickle 
pickle.dump(model111, open("rfc1.pkl","wb"))
```

this give an error :

```
TypeError: can't pickle lock objects
```

i am new in python...is there any way to unlock m model so i can use the pickle or can someone please suggest to me any solution

Comment: What is your question? The error seems pretty clear: you can't pickle that object.

Comment: but i want to save my model "model111"

Comment: Well, you simply can't. Lock objects can't be pickled, regardless of their state.